Home internet connection speed is slow
I subscribe to a 300Mbps ISP fiber service. My son has his PC connected via LAN directly to the LAN port on the provider's modem/router and is getting +300Mbps.
My PC is connected via LAN to a gigabit switch that connects to the router but I'm only getting 90+Mbps. I'm using CAT6 cables for all wired connections. I'm expecting a connection speed closer to 300.

Does your PC report a 1 Gbps link speed for the Ethernet interface? Does the router report its port link speeds anywhere in its settings? Does the switch, at least, have LEDs indicating the link mode?

My PC's ethernet interface is 2.5Gbps. I checked my router ethernet port link (port 1) and it's at 100Mbps. There is one used port (port 2, my son's PC) running at 1000M. The ethernet list shows port 4 at 1000M but when I switched the cable to that port it goes to 100M. The switch LED is lit but I don't see any mode indication.

Your PC can do 2.5 Gbps maximum, but the question is what link speed it negotiates in practice, as there are several fixed modes. Windows 11 has the information in its "new" network settings but I usually use Get-NetAdapter from PowerShell. (There are two links here – from PC to switch, and from switch to router – and you need to check the actual link speed/rate/mode of each of them to narrow down the problem.)

So if you say that the router reports 100 Mbps for the port that the switch is attached to, and if you're very sure that both the router and the switch are capable of 1 Gbps on their respective ports, then I'd suggest trying a different cable – Cat5e is fine – and other combinations, e.g. different ports.

Ok, thanks for the tip. Appreciate it!

@NikZurin - Be sure to make any edits to your question so an answer can be submitted.

I think one thing potentially missing from the description is whether there are any in-the-wall cables involved (e.g. electrician-installed ethernet wall jacks)

When you have gigabit (1000BASE-T) or better Ethernet equipment at both ends and only make a 100Mbps (100BASE-T) link, it's a telltale sign of a problem with the cabling on the third or fourth twisted pair (pins 4&5 or pins 7&8). 100BASE-T only used the first two pairs, but 1000BASE-T and later require all 4 pairs.
Swap out cables with known-good cables if you can. Otherwise, look for damage on your cable or connectors, or a poor termination job (poorly crimped male connectors, poorly punched-down wires on the back of the female connectors). Consider using a cheap UTP cable continuity/pinout tester (the "light up the LED for pins 1-8 in order" kind) to verify the integrity of the cable.
Note that cheap pinout testers can't detect a split pair, so make sure you're using the same standard pinout (one of either T568A or T568B) at both ends of each cable. It's fine to mix and match cables that use T568A and T568B, but any single cable needs to use exactly one of those two pinouts at both ends. You can't do T568A at one end and T568B at the other of the cable.
Some common connector damage to look out for:

Bent plastic vanes between pins of a male connector, which block the pins of the female connector from making contact.
Bent or broken/missing pins within a female connector.
Debris inside a female connector.

In some cases, the damaged signal path ends up being inside the device. A common example is a cracked solder joint where the female RJ-45 connector solders onto the PCB.

I think Gigabit Ethernet interfaces should be okay with T568A on one end and T568B on another – that's just legacy crossover if I remember correctly, which AFAIK is still handled by 1000BASE-T automatic crossover. (On the other hand, specification suggests that 1000BASE-T should recognize any swapped pairs, but I've had devices where that barely worked and devices where it didn't work at all.)

A less likely, but still possible, cause could be settings for the ethernet device in the operating system.
